# How to write the JQ expression for dynamic partitioning from Kinesis console in CDK Kinesis configuration parameters?

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a JQ expression for dynamic partitioning in the Kinesis firehose as follows:

```
Key name     JQ expression
time        .time| strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") | mktime | strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

This was written for the below time format:

```
"time": "2020-01-29T17:26:50Z"
```

The above JQ expression gives me time format output as `20200129` which I use as my partition date while storing records from Kinesis.

How should I write it in the config parameters while writing Kinesis firehose code in AWS CDK?

```
s3_destination_conf = ds.ExtendedS3DestinationConfigurationProperty(
    bucket_arn=output_bucket.bucket_arn,
    dynamic_partitioning_configuration=ds.DynamicPartitioningConfigurationProperty(
        enabled=True
    ),
    processing_configuration=ds.ProcessingConfigurationProperty(
        enabled=True,
        processors=[
            ds.ProcessorProperty(
                type="MetadataExtraction",
                parameters=[
                    ds.ProcessorParameterProperty(
                        parameter_name="JsonParsingEngine",
                        parameter_value="JQ-1.6",
                    ),
                    ds.ProcessorParameterProperty(
                        parameter_name="MetadataExtractionQuery",
 ==== Issue line =>     parameter_value="{time: .time| strptime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') | mktime | strftime('%Y%m%d')}", 
                    ),
                ],
            )
        ],
    ),
    role_arn=role.role_arn,
    buffering_hints=ds.BufferingHintsProperty(
        interval_in_seconds=params.KinesisFirehose.BUFFER_INTERVAL_SEC,
        size_in_m_bs=params.KinesisFirehose.BUFFER_SIZE_MB,
    ),
```

I tried playing a bit with the double quotes and single quotes in the JQ string(`parameter_value="{time: .time| strptime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') | mktime | strftime('%Y%m%d')}"`) but it didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
parameter_value="{time: .time| strptime(\'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ\') | mktime | strftime(\'%Y%m%d\')}"
```

You can also have a look on the string escape characters in python [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp).